# Python scrape join following-sibling

Tags: python, scrapy

Sorry if i wrong use title. Basically i want scrape this data using scrapy :

```html
<tr>
    <td colspan=2>
        <h4>Ottawa Macdonald-Cartier International Airport runways</h4>
    </td>
</tr>
</tr>
<tr class="odd">
    <td><a href="ottawa-macdonald-cartier-international-airport-runway-04-22-extended-info_R234949.html" title="Ottawa Macdonald-Cartier International Airport runway 04/22 extended info"><b>04/22</b></a></td>
    <td>3300x75 <small>ft.</small></td>
</tr>
<tr class="even">
    <td><a href="ottawa-macdonald-cartier-international-airport-runway-07-25-extended-info_R234950.html" title="Ottawa Macdonald-Cartier International Airport runway 07/25 extended info"><b>07/25</b></a></td>
    <td>8000x200 <small>ft.</small></td>
</tr>
<tr class="odd">
    <td><a href="ottawa-macdonald-cartier-international-airport-runway-14-32-extended-info_R234951.html" title="Ottawa Macdonald-Cartier International Airport runway 14/32 extended info"><b>14/32</b></a></td>
    <td>10000x200 <small>ft.</small></td>
</tr>
<tr class=""> different repeat each page ....
```

i want output become json format in csv row. so look like :

```
{'05/23': '3281x250 ft.','18/36': '3252x250 ft.'}
```

but i always get result like this :

```
{05/23,18/36,3281x250 ,ft.,3252x250 ,ft.}
```

and this my code :

```
    def parse_details(self, response):
    runway1 = response.xpath(".//tr[contains(.,'runways')]/following-sibling::tr[@class]//td/a[contains(@title,'runway')]//text()").extract()
    runway2 = response.xpath(".//tr[contains(.,'runways')]/following-sibling::tr[@class]//td[contains(.,'ft.')]//text()").extract()
    runway = runway1 + runway2
    runways = ','.join(runway)

    yield {'runways':'{'+runways+'}'}
```

how to make my code can parse like i want ? because i search all tutorial on this website but still stuck. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
key_1 = response.xpath('//tr[@class="odd"]//a/b/text()').extract_first()
value_1 = response.xpath('//tr[@class="odd"]//td[2]/text()').extract_first()

key_2 = response.xpath('//tr[@class="even"]//a/b/text()').extract_first()
value_2 = response.xpath('//tr[@class="even"]//td[2]/text()').extract_first()

yield {key_1: value_1, key_2: value_2}
```

Comment: hi.. thanks for your anwser.. and i'm really sorry. already edit my question, forgot mention if i got different result each page.. sometimes 2 list odd and even, sometimes 5 list..

Answer (score 0):

You can loop on the `tr` header's siblings, and get each key/value:

```
In [1]: response = scrapy.Selector(text='''<tr>
   ...:     <td colspan=2>
   ...:         <h4>Ottawa Macdonald-Cartier International Airport runways</h4>
   ...:     </td>
   ...: </tr>
   ...: </tr>
   ...: <tr class="odd">
   ...:     <td><a href="ottawa-macdonald-cartier-international-airport-runway-04-22-extended-info_R234949.html" title="Ottawa Macdonald-Cartier International Airport runway 04/22 extended info"><b>04/22</b></a></td>
   ...:     <td>3300x75 <small>ft.</small></td>
   ...: </tr>
   ...: <tr class="even">
   ...:     <td><a href="ottawa-macdonald-cartier-international-airport-runway-07-25-extended-info_R234950.html" title="Ottawa Macdonald-Cartier International Airport runway 07/25 extended info"><b>07/25</b></a></td>
   ...:     <td>8000x200 <small>ft.</small></td>
   ...: </tr>
   ...: <tr class="odd">
   ...:     <td><a href="ottawa-macdonald-cartier-international-airport-runway-14-32-extended-info_R234951.html" title="Ottawa Macdonald-Cartier International Airport runway 14/32 extended info"><b>14/32</b></a></td>
   ...:     <td>10000x200 <small>ft.</small></td>
   ...: </tr>''')



In [2]: {tr.xpath('string(.//td/a[contains(@title,"runway")])').get():
   ...:      tr.xpath('string(.//td[contains(.,"ft.")])').get()
   ...:  for tr in response.xpath('.//tr[contains(., "runways")]/following-sibling::tr[@class]')    }
   ...:  
Out[2]: 
{u'04/22': u'3300x75 ft.',
 u'07/25': u'8000x200 ft.',
 u'14/32': u'10000x200 ft.'}
```

An example callback might look like:

```
def parse_details(self, response):
    for tr in response.xpath('.//tr[contains(., "runways")]/following-sibling::tr[@class]'):
        yield {tr.xpath('string(.//td/a[contains(@title,"runway")])').get():
                    tr.xpath('string(.//td[contains(.,"ft.")])').get()}
```

Comment: hi.. thanks for your answer.. can you give me sample def parser with yield output from your command above ? i'm still new in python..